# Windows Start Menu Search Results Displaying Funky

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I thought it would be cute to let my 10 month old baby bang on my keyboard and now my Start Menu search results look super funky. Here is what it looks like when I search for "cmd":

[image: funky start menu]

And when I right click on cmd the options show up under all of the results. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?